# Flot chart loss some options on update

Tags: charts, real-time, flot, updating

I'm trying to create an interactive and real-time graph using flot library. It's very similar to the real-time example in Flot site but with some additional options.
This is a part of my code:

```
var bars = false;
var lines = true;
var steps = false;
var xAxisInterval = 5;
var xAxisUnit = "minute";
var plot = 0;


var dataChart = [
    {
        label : "Consumo",
        data : input1_data, //history
        threshold : {below : threshold},
        color : input1_color, //'#00B800',
        lines : {show : input1_show, fill : input1_fill}
    },
    {
        label : "Consumo Previsto",
        data : input2_data, //forecast data
        threshold : {below : threshold},
        //stack : null,
        color : input2_color,//'#66E066',
        lines : {show : input2_show, fill : input2_fill}
    }
];

var plotOptions = {
    lines:{
        show: lines,
        steps: steps
    },
    bars: {
        show: bars,
        barWidth: 0.6
    },
    yaxis:{ min:0, max: 65000 },
    xaxis: { mode : "time", tickSize : [ xAxisInterval, xAxisUnit ] },
    zoom: { interactive : gridZoom },
    pan: { interactive : gridPan },
    points: { show: showPoints },
    grid: { hoverable: gridHoverable, color: gridColor },
    legend: { backgroundColor:legendBackgroundColor, backgroundOpacity:legendBackgroundOpacity, position: legendPosition }
    };

    if (plot == 0) {
        plot = $.plot("#" + divId, dataChart, plotOptions);
    }
    else {
        jQuery.each(dataChart , function(index, value) {
            plot.setData([value.data]);
        });
        plot.setupGrid();
        plot.draw();
    }
```

If i only use the code line $.plot("#"+divId, dataChart, plotOptions), it works well.
[image]

But to improve performance, instead of construt an entire new plot in every time increment, i tryed to use the code in if/else statement. But the ploted chart loss some options, like series colors and legend, and is painted with color defined in grid options (gridColor) ..., as shown in figure below.

[image]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the all the series options with just the data piece.  Also, `setData` replaces all the [data in the chart](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods), so I don't think calling it multiple times in a loop is correct (you'll only end up with the last series).

I usually follow this pattern to replace *just the data*:

```
var series = plot.getData();
for (var i = 0 i < dataChart.length; i++){
    series[i].data = dataChart[i].data;
}
plot.setData(series);
plot.setupGrid();
plot.draw();
```